# the determinant function is an open function?

Tags: linear-algebra

The determinant function $\det:M(n,\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is an open mapping or a closed mapping?

The determinant function $\det:M(n,\mathbb C)\rightarrow \mathbb C$ is an open mapping or a closed mapping?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is an open function! First of all, We will state a standard result about open functions. Suppose $f:X\to Y$. Then $f$ is open if and only if for every point $x$, and every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ so that $V \subset f(U)$. Furthermore, it suffices to assume $U$ is basic open.

I don't know how to prove this simultaneously for invertible and non-invertible matricies, so we'll have to do cases. Sorry it's so long... I'll keep thinking about a simpler solution.

Let's start with the invertible case. Let $\varepsilon >0$. Assume $M$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}$ ($\mathbb{F}$ can be complex or real, it doesn't matter). Then fix a small $x$. (We will figure out how small later.) In the real setting, let $z$ be the $n^\text{th}$ root of $1+x$. in the complex setting we need the root with the smallest argument. I.E.

$$z = \sqrt[n]{|1+x|}e^{(\arg 1+x)/n}$$

Now, assume $x$ is small enough so that
$$
|1-z|<\frac{\varepsilon}{\|M\|}
$$
So we have
$$
\|M-zM\|\leq |1-z|\;\|M\|<\varepsilon
$$

Lastly,
$$
\det(zM)=z^n\det(M)=(1+x)\det M
$$
Now, because $\det M \neq 0$, we can choose $x$ to give us any value nearby $\det M$. So there is some neighborhood $V$ around $\det M$ with $V\subset f[B(M,\varepsilon)]$

We can now get to work on the non-invertible case. Let $\varepsilon >0$. Suppose $M$ is a non-invertible $n\times n$ matrix. Let $M=SJS^{-1}$ be the Jordan decomposition of $M$. Then $J$ is a Jordan form matrix, and we know that at least $1$ of it's diagonal entries is $0$. Let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_i$ be the non-zero eigenvalues. (There many not be any, just let $i=0$ in that case.) Then there are $j:= n-i$ many $0$ diagonal entries. Let $J'$ be the matrix where the first $0$ diagonal is replaced by $x$, and the rest by $|x|$ for some small $x$. ($M$ is singular so there is at least one such entry). Observe
$$
\|M-SJ'S^{-1}\|=|x|
$$

Also,
$$
\det(SJ'S^{-1})=\det J'= x|x|^{j-1}\Pi_{k=0}^i \lambda_k 
$$

So we want $|x|<\varepsilon$. So by choosing $x$ appropriately, we can get a small neighborhood around $0$, call it $V$, where $V\subset f[B(M,\varepsilon)]$

Then then we're done! yay.

Comment: I also didn't use any particularly interesting properties of the matrix norm. Whatever one you were using will probably work here.

Comment: "it suffices to show that for every open U, there is an open V so that V⊂f(U)." This is false. The exponential mapping $[0,2\pi]\to S^1$ satisfies this property but is not an open map.

Comment: Uh, that's right. I misstated what I used. I needed that for every $x$, and for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ with $V\subset U$. That was sloppy of me. I have fixed in the answer above.

Comment: I think the non-invertible case is difficult for me...If we can simplify it.

Comment: The idea is that we need to add something to it to make it invertible. To do that, the simplest way is to use a decomposition that exposes the $0's$. Then replacing those $0's$ by with $x's$, we find something nearby with whatever determinant we want. To this end, there are many equally viable decompositions we can use. What matrix decompositions are you comfortable with? Singular value? QR?

Comment: I think you also need to make another case analysis as to when $j$ is odd or even. For if $j$ is even, then $\det(SJ'S^{-1})$ has the same sign as $\prod_{k=0}^i \lambda_k$ (let's suppose it is positive). Thus $f[B(M,\varepsilon)] = [0,a)$ with $a=\varepsilon^j\prod_{k=0}^i \lambda_k$. So there is no neighbourhood of $0$ that is a subset of this interval $[0,a)$.

Comment: I guess the moral of the story in all these answers is that the real case sucks. Your point well taken, and I will fix it in the morning. Clearly it can be patched by making one of the 0's into a $-x$ when x is negative, but that's ugly. I'll try to think of something nicer.

Answer (score 6):

In the complex case we can use this lemma: Let $P$ be a nonconstant polynomial in $z_1,\dots ,z_m.$ Then $P$ is an open map of $\mathbb {C}^m$ to $\mathbb {C}.$ Since the determinant is a nonconstant polynomial on $\mathbb {C}^{n^2},$ the desired result for $M_n(\mathbb {C})$ follows.

Proof of lemma: Let $B(a,r)$ be an open ball in $\mathbb {C}^m.$ Then $P$ cannot be constant on $B(a,r)$ (this is true of any nonconstant polynomial on any euclidean space). For $w\in \mathbb {C}^m,$ let $P_w(\lambda)= P(a+\lambda w)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb {C}.$ Then each $P_w$ is a holomorphic polynomial on $\mathbb {C}.$ We have

$$P(B(a,r)) = \cup_{\|w\|=1} \{P(a+\lambda w): |\lambda| < r\}.$$

By the open mapping theorem in one complex variable, each $P_w$ is either constant or an open map. Thus each set in the union above is either $\{P(a)\}$ or an open set containing $P(a).$ Because $P$ is nonconstant on $B(a,r),$ some of the sets in the union are open, hence the union is open. This shows $P$ is open as desired.

---

I thought I'd add this proof for the real case: Claim: $\det$ has no local extrema. Suppose we show this. Let $B$ be an open ball in $M_n(\mathbb {R}).$ Because $\det$ is continuous and $B$ is connected, $\det B$ is a bounded interval. This interval cannot take the form $[a,b),[a,b],(a,b],$ otherwise $\det$ has an extremum in $B.$ Thus every $\det (B)$ is an open interval, hence $\det$ is an open map.

Proof of claim: Suppose $\det M \ne 0.$ (This is the easy case.) Let $r>0.$ The map $f(x) =x M$ is continuous from $\mathbb {R}$ to $M_n(\mathbb {R}).$ Thus there is an open interval $I$ about $1$ such that $f(I)\subset B(M,r).$ For these $x$ we have $\det (xM) = x^n \det M,$ from which we can see $\det [B(M,r)]$ includes values above and below $\det M.$ Thus $\det$ does not have a local extremum at $M.$

Now suppose $\det M =0.$ Let $S$ be the linear transformation whose matrix is $M$ (relative to the standard basis). Then we can write $$\mathbb {R}^n = X\oplus \ker S = S(\mathbb {R}^n) \oplus Y,$$ where $m=\dim X = \dim S(\mathbb {R}^n)$ for some $m<n,$ and $\dim \ker S = \dim Y=n-m.$ Let $T$ be a linear transformation such that $T = 0$ on $X,T(\ker S) = Y.$ Then $S+xT$ is nonsingular for $x\in \mathbb {R},x\ne 0.$ Hence $\det (S+xT)\ne 0$ for such $x.$ To make sure we have both positive and negative values, let $u_1,\dots, u_m$ be a basis for $X,$ $u_{m+1},\dots u_n$ a basis for $\ker T.$ Let $T'$ be the linear transformation such that $T'=T$ on this basis except for $u_n,$ where we define $T'(u_n) = - T(u_n).$ Then $\det (S+xT') = -\det (S+xT),$ which you can see by looking at the matrices of these transformations with respect to the basis $u_1,\dots ,u_n.$

If we now let $M(x),M'(x)$ be the matrices of $S+xT, S+xT'$ with respect to the standard basis, we see that $\det$ takes on positive and negative values in any $B(M,r).$ That finishes the proof.

Comment: You want to know why the left side of (1) contains the right side?

Comment: If $\|N-M\|<r,$ then $t\|N-M\|<r$ for some $t>1.$ We have $N=M+(1/t)\cdot (t(N-M)).$ This shows the left side of (1) is contained in the right side. That the right side is contained in the left side is clear I hope.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That removed my doubts. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, I changed my answer a bit and hopefully improved it.

Comment: I also added a proof for the real case.

Comment: No, $T(\mathbb {R}^n) = Y.$

Comment: No, $S$ maps $X$ to $S(\mathbb{R}^n).$ The idea is that $S$ "lives on $X,$ $T$ lives on $\ker S.$"

Answer (score 4):

To complement Zach Stone's nice answer, notice also that $\det$ is **not** a closed map for $n\ge2$ (if $n=1$, then $\det = \operatorname{id}$). Indeed, in both cases you can consider the set of matrices that are given by
$$M_t=\pmatrix{t&0\\0&\frac{1}{t^2}}$$
in the upper left corner and correspond with the identity matrix everywhere else for $t$ running on $(0,\infty)$. It is closed, as we have
$$\|M_t\| = \cases{t&if $t\ge1$\\ \frac{1}{t^2}&if $t\le1$}$$
and thus any convergent sequence in this set must be of the type $\{M_{t_n}\}_n$ with $\{t_n\}_n$ converging to a finite, non-zero number (else the norm would diverge). However, we have that
$$\det(\{M_t|t\in(0,\infty)\}) = (0,\infty),$$
which is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach for the invertible case:

Fix an invertible matrix $A$, and let $B$ be any matrix, then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\biggr|_{t=0} \det(A+tAB) = \det(A)\frac{d}{dt}\biggr|_{t=0} \det(I+tB) = \det(A)\mathrm{tr}(B)
$$

Since we can pick matrices of arbitrarily small norm with positive and negative traces, we get that $\det$ is an open map about $A$.