# Is determinant a closed map?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I know that determinant as a map from set $n×n$ matrices to $\Bbb{R}$ is an open map but I wonder whether it is closed map too?I don't know how to prove or disprove but intuitively it seems to me that it is not closed.Any help is appreciable

Thanks.

Comment: See the answer @Daniel Robert-Nicoud gave to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311464/the-determinant-function-is-an-open-function)

Comment: @Peter Melech very nice answer...thanks for your help

Comment: @lbs You're welcome!

Comment: @peter what about trace of matrix? Is it closed,.....again trace is open but can't think whether it a closed map!

Comment: It is not closed.  Consider $A=\{\operatorname{diag}(n+n^{-1},-n)\mid n=1,2,3,\dots\}$ and trace maps $A$ to $\{n^{-1}\mid n=1,2,3,\dots\}$.

Comment: @Dietrich yes that helps as suggested by peter